# Python - Bottle & Pillow - Return image to browser

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, bottle

I use Bottle Framework and Pillow, I want to generate an image on the fly and display it to the browers using the endpoint.

I have :

```
try:
    img = Image.open("images/template.png")
    
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("fonts/arial.ttf", 40)
    
    draw.text((23, 62), "Text", "#000", font=font)
    
    # image save works
    img.save("test_save.png")
    
    response.content_type = 'image/png'
    
    return io.BytesIO(img.tobytes())
except OSError as exception:
    print(exception)
    pass
```

The image saved is perfect, but the image displayed to browser is only an empty square with bad dimensions.

I looked at Stackoverflow to find what I wrote, but I guess I missed something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at a computer to test my code, but you need to return a PNG-encoded image, so you need to tell **PIL** to write into a BytesIO rather than to disk. Something like:

```
from io import BytesIO

# Write PIL Image to in-memory PNG
membuf = BytesIO()
img.save(membuf, format="png")
```

... you can now send `membuf.getvalue()` and if you check the first few bytes they will look exactly the same as if you dump any other, regular PNG file from your disk.