# Python: how to convert an image in memory?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-conversion

I have an image in memory (downloaded from an online source) and I want to convert it to a different format before sending it on to a different online location.
The conversion is .webp to .jpg but that's not really relevant.

With Pillow I can easily convert local images and save them back to disc, but I can't get it to work with an image in memory.

I don't necessarily need to use Pillow. Any way to convert the image without having to save anything to disc is fine.

Comment: Just save one BytesIO object to another.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/67809064/2836621

Answer (score 0):

I am new to BytesIO with PIL, so just check my code attempt, with my test image it works, let me know

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO



img = Image.open('test.webp')
print('image : ', img.format)
img.show()


# Write PIL Image to in-memory PNG
membuf = BytesIO()
img.save(membuf, format="png") 

img = Image.open(membuf)

print('image : ', img.format)
img.show()
```